# glossaries: Calculating the width of custom field

Tags: tables, glossaries, glossaries-extra

For the following MWE

```
% arara: lualatex: { options: [ '-synctex=1', '-shell-escape' ]}
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: lualatex: { options: [ '-synctex=1', '-shell-escape' ]}

\documentclass{elsarticle}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{calc,siunitx,booktabs,lipsum}
\sisetup{load-configurations = abbreviations}
\usepackage[automake,stylemods,symbols,
xindy={codepage=utf8, language=greek, glsnumbers=false}
]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\newlength\glsnamewidth
\newlength\glsunitwidth
\settowidth{\glsnamewidth}{\textbf{sign}}
\settowidth{\glsunitwidth}{\textbf{unit}}

\newglossarystyle{nameunitdesc}{%
    \setlength{\glsdescwidth}{\linewidth-\glsnamewidth-\glsunitwidth-4\tabcolsep}%
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\begin{supertabular}{@{}p{\glsnamewidth}p{\glsunitwidth}p{\glsdescwidth}@{}}\toprule\addlinespace[5pt]}%
        {\bottomrule\end{supertabular}}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
    \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
        \raggedright\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} & 
        \centering\glossentrysymbol{##1} &
        \glossentrydesc{##1}\tabularnewline
    }%
    \renewcommand{\subglossentry}[3]{\glossentry{##2}{##3}}%
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
}

\glsnoexpandfields

\newglossaryentry{Cp}{name={Cp},description={specific heat}, symbol={[\si{\J\per\kg\per\K}]}}

\journal{Journal name}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frontmatter}

        \title{Title}

        \begin{abstract}

            \lipsum[1]

        \end{abstract}

    \end{frontmatter}

    \gls{Cp} 

    \glsFindWidestUsedAnyNameSymbol{\glsunitwidth}
    \settowidth{\dimen0}{\glsgetwidestname}
    \ifdim\dimen0>\glsnamewidth
    \glsnamewidth=\dimen0
    \fi

    \printglossary[style=nameunitdesc,title=Nomenclature]

\end{document}
```

In this line `\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{\linewidth-\glsnamewidth-\glsunitwidth-2\tabcolsep}`, intuitively, I need to subtract `2\tabcolsep` in order to make the description field span the whole line width, however, subtracting `4\tabcolsep` results in the following correctly aligned right margin of the glossary table:

[image]

while subtracting `2\tabcolsep` results in the following overflown right margin of the glossary table:

[image]

So, how to accurately calculate the needed number of `\tabcolsep` to be subtracted without trial and error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually has nothing to do with `glossaries`, it is just how `tabular` works:

`\tabcolsep` is the margin that is inserted *on either side* of every column in the table. Thus, in the example

```
\begin{tabular}{ c c c }
  \hline
  a & b & c \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image: MWE output]

the table extends `\tabcolsep` to the left of `a` and to the right of `c` (you can see the width of the table using the `\hline`s), while there is a space of `2\tabcolsep` between `a` and `b` as well as `b` and `c`.

In your example, you remove the separations at the edges of the table using `@{}` and you have three columns. That makes `2 * 2\tabcolsep = 4\tabcolsep` between them.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Off topic question: how to remove both separations on each side of the first column in your example while keeping all the other ones?

Comment: @Diaa You can use `{ @{} c @{\hspace{\tabcolsep}} c c }` as the column specifier.

Comment: Thanks for help. I am always in rush and struggle a lot with latex basics :)